# Combine three MySQL query results into one result ordered properly

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table whose query results I need to order by the following criteria:

1) Ranking value of 100 or greater   (sorted highest to lowest)

2) List_Date  - Most recent to oldest within the last 90 days.

3) Ranking values less than 100       (sorted highest to lowest)

I tried the following, but realized it won't work as per the MySQL docs, "because UNION by default produces an unordered set of rows."

```
(SELECT Ranking, List_Date 
FROM example_table
WHERE Ranking > 100
ORDER BY Ranking DESC)

UNION

(SELECT Ranking, List_Date 
FROM example_table
WHERE List_Date BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 90 DAY AND CURDATE()
ORDER BY List_Date DESC)

UNION

(SELECT Ranking, List_Date 
FROM example_table
WHERE Ranking < 100
ORDER BY Ranking DESC)
```

I would like to figure out how to keep the ordering along the three statements.  Possible?

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't look like you need to use `UNION` as your where condition can be combined using `OR`. Try this:

```
SELECT Ranking, List_Date 
FROM example_table
WHERE Ranking <> 100 
OR List_Date BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 90 DAY AND CURDATE()
ORDER BY Ranking, List_Date DESC
```

Comment: This doesn't do it. 

Need the results to return first Rankings, 123, 121, 103 then dates 2015-11-05, 2015-11-03, then Rankings 87, 76, 23, etc.  With no repeats.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you really need the `UNION` because as mentioned in other answers your example could be resolved without it and usually it affects performance. You can wrap it all in a new `SELECT` statement.

```
SELECT * FROM (
(SELECT Ranking, List_Date 
FROM example_table
WHERE Ranking > 100
ORDER BY Ranking DESC)

UNION

(SELECT Ranking, List_Date 
FROM example_table
WHERE List_Date BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 90 DAY AND CURDATE()
ORDER BY List_Date DESC)

UNION

(SELECT Ranking, List_Date 
FROM example_table
WHERE Ranking < 100
ORDER BY Ranking DESC)

) AS NEW_TEMP 
ORDER BY NEW_TEMP.Ranking, NEW_TEMP.List_Date DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, while the answers I received didn't directly solve my problem, they pointed me in the right direction.  Here's my solution.  It works, but might be un-elegant.

```
SELECT * FROM (
(SELECT (@cnt := @cnt + 1) AS rowNumber, Ranking, List_Date 
FROM example_table
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @cnt := 0) AS dummy
WHERE Ranking > 100
ORDER BY Ranking DESC)

UNION

(SELECT (@cnt := @cnt + 1) AS rowNumber, Ranking, List_Date 
FROM example_table
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @cnt := (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `example_table `)) AS dummy
WHERE List_Date BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 90 DAY AND CURDATE()
ORDER BY List_Date DESC)

UNION

(SELECT (@cnt := @cnt + 1) AS rowNumber, Ranking, List_Date 
FROM example_table
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @cnt := ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `example_table `) * 2)) AS dummy
WHERE Ranking < 100
ORDER BY Ranking DESC)
) as T
ORDER BY rowNumber DESC
```